# Can Boolean operators ever produce a non-Boolean result?

Tags: c#

Please note, this question is not about the correctness of this style/convention, only about the use of Boolean operators. Just wanted to mention the style to give context.

Microsoft's [C# Coding Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions#implicitly-typed-local-variables) states that implicit typing is allowed "for local variables when the type of the variable is obvious from the right side of the assignment."

In the following code:

```
bool x = X();
bool y = Y();

var z = x && y;
```

Does the Boolean operator in the declaration of `z` make its type "obvious"? In other words, is there any situation in C# where `&&` can be used with an `x` and `y` that are not Boolean, and produce a result that is not Boolean?

Comment: short-circuit and (`&&`) of two boolean values can't return anything else than a boolean value.

Comment: The `&&` operator only works on `bool` types. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-) for more info: *"The conditional logical AND operator &&, also known as the "short-circuiting" logical AND operator, computes the logical AND of its operands. The result of x && y is true if both x and y evaluate to true. Otherwise, the result is false. If the first operand evaluates to false, the second operand is not evaluated."*

Comment: Also:  boolean logic operators cannot be overloaded or overridden in C#, so the documentation cited by Rufus is always true.

Comment: @Amy [True and false operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/true-false-operators) can be overridden to produce some very strange results...

Comment: If you use (newer) versions of Visual Studio, you can hold the mouse over the `&&` operator and wait for a tooltip. The tooltip will give you a hint about whether the usual predefined overload of `&&` (which has return type `bool`) is picked. Or if a set of user-defined operators is chosen instead as the best overload.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for that to return something that is not a boolean *as long as it can be evaluated as a boolean*.

This requires you to overload the `true` and `false` operators, take this strange type:

```
public class MyStrangeType
{
    public static readonly MyStrangeType Strange1 = new MyStrangeType(0);
    public static readonly MyStrangeType Strange2 = new MyStrangeType(1);

    private int myValue;

    public int Value { get { return myValue; } }

    private MyStrangeType(int value)
    {
        myValue = value;    
    }

    public static bool operator true(MyStrangeType x) { return x.myValue == 1; } 
    public static bool operator false(MyStrangeType x) { return x.myValue != 1; }

    public static MyStrangeType operator &(MyStrangeType x, MyStrangeType y)
    {
        return new MyStrangeType(3);    
    }
}
```

Now when you do something like this:

```
var result = MyStrangeType.Strange1 && MyStrangeType.Strange2;
```

`result` is **not a boolean** but a `MyStrangeType`.

[Try it out!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JYA90f)

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var result = MyStrangeType.Strange1 && MyStrangeType.Strange2;

        Console.WriteLine(result.GetType().FullName);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

> MyStrangeType

Answer (score 6):

Are `&&` and `||` guaranteed to return a boolean? No. Will they almost always result in a boolean? Most definitely.

By way of a counter example for `&&` returning a non-boolean, consider the following:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Val { get; }
    public Foo(int val) { Val = val; }
    
    public static bool operator true(Foo val) {
        return val.Val > 0;
    }
    public static bool operator false(Foo val) {
        return val.Val <= 0;
    }
    
    public static Foo operator &(Foo left, Foo right) {
        return new Foo(left.Val & right.Val);
    }
    public static Foo operator |(Foo left, Foo right) {
        return new Foo(left.Val | right.Val);
    }
}
```

Now we have a class that has indirectly overloaded the `&&` and `||` operators, and they return type `Foo`.

The specification has this to say about user defined `&&` and `||` operators:

> When the operands of && or || are of types that declare an applicable user-defined operator & or operator |, both of the following must be true, where T is the type in which the selected operator is declared:
>
> •  The return type and the type of each parameter of the selected operator must be T. In other words, the operator must compute the logical AND or the logical OR of two operands of type T, and must return a result of type T.
>
> •  T must contain declarations of operator true and operator false.

Now, we evaluate the following:

```
var foo = new Foo(5) && new Foo(4);
```

`foo` is of Type `Foo`, with a `Val` of 4, as 5 & 4 is 4.

All of that said, I would not expect to see this kind of behavior outside of very specific circumstances.

Additionally, as the specification points out, the result of `&&` or `||` must be the type of the parameters. In a `bool && bool` or `bool || bool` scenario, this should always be `bool`. So long as you're doing your logical operations on booleans (and not strange random non-boolean types) you should expect the result to be a `bool`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer (and I apologize for the late upvote and response). Currently I'm torn between selecting your answer or Ron Beyer's as accepted, as they are essentially the same, and they both answer my question. I think I have to go with Ron's since his was first. (If I missed something that makes yours better, let me know!)

Answer (score 0):

I could maybe misunderstood your question but this maybe could help to you or someone else. 
There is "is" operator. You can check a veriable is a type of something.
For example;
var z = x is bool && y is bool;

Comment: Yes, I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: Such use of the `is` operator is meaningless. For that reason you get the warning _warning CS0183: The given expression is always of the provided ('bool') type_ if you do it. There is no reason to say `x is T` if the compile-time type of `x` is a value type (or more generally a sealed type).

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate questions.

> is there any situation in C# where && can be used with an x and y
>   that are not Boolean, and produce a result that is not Boolean?

This is shown by the other answers.

> Does the Boolean operator in the declaration of z make its type "obvious"?

Yes, if `x` and `y` are bools. Since the `&&` operator applied on boolean operands always returns a `bool`, which is defined in the specification. C# doesn't really allow variable return types for the same overload, except for  the case of using the `dynamic` keyword. But then `var` is just inferred as `dynamic`  as well.

Comment: I would disagree that `x` and `y` being bools makes the type of `z` obvious. The style says the type of `z` must be made obvious by `the right-hand side of the declaration`, not by `lines above`. `x` and `y` could have been declared much further up, and then it is not obvious at all unless you are using an editor like VS that allows you to mouseover and see the type. I was specifically asking if the operator makes `z` obvious, because I do not believe that `x` and `y` make it obvious.